# Replacing Content of a column with part of that column's content

Tags: r, replace, command, gsub, expand

I'd like to replace the content of a column in a data frame with only a specific word in that column.

The column always looks like this:

```
Place(fullName='Würzburg, Germany', name='Würzburg', type='city', country='Germany', countryCode='DE')
Place(fullName='Iphofen, Deutschland', name='Iphofen', type='city', country='Germany', countryCode='DE')
```

I'd like to extract the city name (in this case Würzburg or Iphofen) into a new column, or replace the entire row with the name of the town. There are many different towns so having a gsub-command for every city name will be tough.
Is there a way to maybe just use a gsub and tell Rstudio to replace whatever it finds inside the first two ' '?
Might it be possible to tell it, "give me the word after "name=' until the next '?
I'm very new to using R so I'm kind of out of ideas.
Thanks a lot for any help!

I know of the gsub command, but I don't think it will be the most appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with a regular expression you can do exactly that:

```
string <- "Place(fullName='Würzburg, Germany', name='Würzburg', type='city', country='Germany', countryCode='DE')"
city <- gsub(".*name='(.*?)'.*", "\\1", string)
```

The regular expression says "match any characters followed by name=', then capture any characters until the next ' and then match any additional characters". Then you replace all of that with just the captured characters ("\\1").

The parentheses mean "capture this part", and the value becomes "\\1". (You can do multiple captures, with subsequent captures being \\2, \\3, etc.

Note the question mark in (.*?). This means "match as little as possible while still satisfying the rest of the regex". If you don't include the question mark, the regular expression will match "greedily" and you will capture the entire rest of the line instead of just the city since that would also satisfy the regular expression.

More about regular expression (specific to R) can be found [here](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/regex-r-regular-expressions-guide)

Comment: Hey erikor, thank you very much for your reply! You really helped me out a lot, your solution worked! 
All I had to do was to change the word string to the name of my data frame and save it in a new column. Worked like a charm!
Again, thank you very much!